# iPad pop-up notetaking

Tags: ipad

To serve the same basic purpose as my question about split-screen apps:

Is there an app that allows me to quickly (in one touch or zero!) bring up a notepad/text editor while I'm in another app?

This would be immensely useful for things like taking notes on a PDF that I'm viewing.
.
I realize that certain apps may include note taking functionality, but these do not suit the need for a universal way of taking notes, which TextEdit on my Mac does nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily get this by running any text editor (even Mail would do) in parallel to the main app and then use the new (iOS 5/iPad 2) four finger swipe (or a double-tab on the home button to get the list of applications) to switch between the app and the note.

Comment: FWIW, The four finger swipe only works on an iPad 2.